# Passing a complex object to the view and posting it back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a MVC 5 application.

I've got an action taking a complex object as a parameter. This action generates a view, and this view calls another action, that needs this complex object to be passed to it.

What's the bast way to pass it along, avoiding storing it in the session (I know, that would be the simplest to do, but one of the project requirements is to avoid using session except for security things) ?

Example controller:

```
public class TestController {
    public ActionResult Action1(ComplexObject object)
    {
        TestModel model = new TestModel
        {
            model.ComplexObject = complexObject
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action2(TestModel model)
    {
        DoSomeStuff(model.ComplexObject);

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

So the problem is to store this complex object somewhere (again, not in session) to be able to retrieve it in the Action2 the way it existed in Action1. I currently add it to the model, but it's not mandatory, as it is not used in the view.

I thought of creating hidden fields in the view, but storing everything from the object is a real pain in the ass, it's ugly, and would introduce errors if the object structure changes in the future.

Is there a good practice to do something like this ? Or is there a elegant way to somehow serialize and deserialize it ? Any idea welcome.

Comment: Unless `ComplexObject` is persisted in some other way (perhaps original came from a database), then no. You must either use the session or you must post every single property back.

Comment: Personally, while I wouldn't recommend it as it seems pointless to build this object, pass it out, then accept it back somehow, i would say it would be possible with a hiddenfield that contains a base64 string of the object serialised into bytes.  your post action will need need to reserialise it afterwards.

Comment: Though, you could try `TempData`. Technically, `TempData` uses `Session` under the hood, so it's still using sessions, but the data is only persisted until the following request and then removed. Perhaps, that doesn't violate the *spirit* of your requirements, though it does technically violate the letter. You'll most likely need to discuss it with your stakeholder.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for confirming what I suspected. I'll try TempData, hoping the spirit is more important than the letter :)

Answer (score 0):

If your TestModel definition has a ComplexObject (which I imagine it does because you are assigning the ComplexObject value to it), when you pass that model to the view, as you are doing in Action1 your view will receive it as long as you have strongly typed your view as such:

```
@model = TestModel //simplified path since I do not know the full path of your model
```

Your Action2 method is an HttpPost which makes me conclude that you will have a user post the form on the view.  When the form is posted, your strongly typed view will pass the model into your Action2 method.  If you use any HTML helpers to modify any of the properties of TestModel, then those changes will be passed to your Action2 method as well.